# Can I automate a Docker image build for a public repo I'm not a member of?

Tags: github, docker, webhooks

I'd like to learn if there is a work around to automatically build a docker container up in hub.docker.com for a Dockerfile in a repo that is public, but I am not a member of.

So far the only way I can see to accomplish this is to have [read/write access to the git repo](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/github/#linking-docker-hub-to-a-github-account.) (yes I can fork it, but I have to manually keep updating it).

I'm looking for a way that can be automatic based on the repo having updates to the master branch pushed.

Update - was definitely hoping for a tool or strategy to do this...I'm accepting the below answer because I can't figure a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.  Fork the git repository.  Sign up or sign in Docker Hub and create a repository linked to your forked git repo, and follow these steps:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#link-to-a-hosted-repository-service

Comment: The problem with forking it is I have to manually keep the repo up to date. I wish to be able to build this automatically when the 3rd party pushes an update to the master branch.

Comment: I ended up making a private fork. I wonder if there are new ways.